# Change iframe height with JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i want to change the height of an iframe with Jquery (the iframe is runat=server).
And height does not change.

What's wrong with my code??

**iframe tag:**

```
  <iframe  style="height: 956px; width: 100%" frameborder="0" runat="server" id="ift"></iframe>
```

And JQuery:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $(window).resize(function () {


            $('#ift').height($(window).height())


        });

    });
```

Comment: Works as I would expect: http://jsfiddle.net/7c49hjf2/ Resize the output section and you will see the height change. What are you needing?

Comment: i  want the iframe height to be equal to the page height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `ClientIDMode="Static"` to your iframe. 
Alternatively you can add a class to your iframe and target the class instead of the id like so

```
$('.YourIframeCSSclass').height($(window).height());
```

Also you forgot to put a semicolon after resizing the Iframe.

Answer (score 1):

If it's `runat=server` you can't guarantee the id since ASP.NET changes it. Try:

```
<iframe  style="height: 956px; width: 100%" frameborder="0" runat="server" id="ift" ClientIDMode="Static"></iframe>
```